# Unable to dequeue view needed as cell for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a UICollectionView with a custom class that is subclassing UICollectionViewCell. I keep getting the following error:

> reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind:
>   UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Appointment - must
>   register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype
>   cell in a storyboard'

I have however done the following:

Registered the custom class with the collectionView.

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(AppointmentCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"Appointment");
```

Here is my dequeue line:

```
let appointmentCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Appointment", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AppointmentCollectionViewCell;
```

This is what my AppointmentCollectionViewCell looks like:

```
class AppointmentCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftBorderView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var appointmentLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func setAppointment(appointment:Appointment){
        self.leftBorderView.backgroundColor = appointment.eventColour;
        self.appointmentLabel.textColor = appointment.eventColour;
        self.backgroundColor = appointment.eventColour.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2);
    }

}
```

I have also in the view provided the reuse identifier to be "Appointment".

[image]

I've also tried the following based on answers posted here - still not working:

```
let appointmentNib = UINib(nibName: "AppointmentCollectionViewCell", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())
        self.collectionView.registerNib(appointmentNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Appointment")
```

After googling, most people forget to register the class. In my case I have registered the class but still keep getting the error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you properly typed 'Appointment' in the the Interface Builder? After selection of cell in storyboard, open Attribute inspector and check Identifier field ... ?

Comment: @pedrouan, I've updated the post based on your comment

Comment: cell identifier in storyboard is not necessary If you are registering cell identifier programmatically

Comment: If the cell is a prototype cell in your storyboard then you should not be registering anything in code.

Comment: @dan the cell isn't prototype, its a custom cell

Comment: can you not call registerCell method from code and set type and identifier of cell from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is associated with a xib file you need to use the registerNib method, not the registerClass method.

```
func registerNib(_ nib: UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)

You also seem to be confusing Collection Reusable View and UICollectionViewCell - which is it? Both have specific registration methods, check the documentation.

Comment: I dont follow your last post update, "You also seem to be confusing Collection Reusable View and UICollectionViewCell" please elaborate, may I am confusing something

Answer (score 0):

First Check:

1. You have a Xib which have class **AppointmentCollectionViewCell**
2. Get Nib from class
   For e.g.
   `UINib *favouritesNib = [UINib nibFromClass:[TNYCellRestaurantAnchorclass]];`
3. Register the Nib to CollectionView

   `[self.collectionViewName registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"identifier name"];`